# What Am I doing wrong? Cannot open SQLite database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite

Please I am trying to load all Tables in SQLite database into combobox I keep getting the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Additional information: Invalid ConnectionString format for part "C:\SQliteTest\sqlite_test\bin\Debug\test.db", no equal sign found:

The following is my code. VS keeps highlighting:
       SQLconnect.Open()

Dim db As String = "C:\SQliteTest\sqlite_test\bin\Debug\test.db; Version=3;"

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
    Dim SQLcommand As SQLiteCommand
    SQLconnect.ConnectionString = db
    SQLconnect.Open()
    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
    Dim SchemaTable = SQLconnect.GetSchema(SQLiteMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables)
    For int As Integer = 0 To SchemaTable.Rows.Count - 1
        If SchemaTable.Rows(int)!TABLE_TYPE.ToString = "table" Then
            Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(SchemaTable.Rows(int)!TABLE_NAME.ToString())
        End If
    Next
    SQLcommand.Dispose()
    SQLconnect.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the SQLite.NET provider the connection should probably look like below:

`Dim db As String = "Data Source=C:\SQliteTest\sqlite_test\bin\Debug\test.db; Version=3;"`

See [The Connection Strings Reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite-net-provider/basic/) for more information and samples.

Comment: Than you. That resolved the problem BUT I have another issue and that is any database I create from an sqlite app doesnt open. i keep getting the following error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Additional information: unable to open database file

Comment: If my answer solved the problem in the question you should consider accepting it, and since other problems remain  post another question so that more people can take a look at it.